# Check datatable has another datatable values - C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have below code, that has a datatable `dt`. And I have one more datatable named `dt1`. I want to check `dt` has `dt1` data before merge both table. If `dt` already has `dt1` data I don't want to merge both datatable.

Ideally looking for a `dt.Exists(dt1)` like code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)),
                                                new DataColumn("Acount", typeof(string)),
                                                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                                                new DataColumn("Quarter", typeof(string)),
                                                new DataColumn("FY", typeof(int)),
                                                new DataColumn("Income_percent", typeof(int))});

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "ABC", "Ram", "Q1", 2011, 50);
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "XYZ", "Hari", "Q4", 2011, 35);
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "ABC", "Rohit", "Q3", 2011, 40);
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "ABC", "Ram", "Q2", 2011, 25);
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "XYZ", "Hari", "Q3", 2011, 60);

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Rows.Add(3, "ABC", "Rohit", "Q3", 2011, 40);
        dt1.Rows.Add(4, "ABC", "Ram", "Q2", 2011, 25);
        dt1.Rows.Add(5, "XYZ", "Hari", "Q3", 2011, 60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
public DataTable getLinq(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
 {
   DataTable dtMerged = 
        (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                join b in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                  on 
        a["Query"].ToString() equals b["Query"].ToString()
                                into g
                      where g.Count() > 0
               select a).CopyToDataTable();
            return dtMerged;
 }
```

For more Info see [here](http://forgetcode.com/CSharp/1508-Comparing-two-datatables-and-returning-a-datatable-by-matching-one-or-more-columns-using-LINQ)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data is based on the ID column. In such case you can use Linq to compare both data tables:

```
IEnumerable<int> idsInDt = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["ID"]);
IEnumerable<int> idsInDt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["ID"]);

IEnumerable<int> newRows = idsInDt1.Except(idsInDt);
```

Then you simply need to verify the count and merge new lines based on `ID`

```
if(newRows.Count > 0)
    // Copy new lines
```

Comment: if you are talking about IDs then your IEnumerable should be int not string

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
 var diff = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(dt1.AsEnumerable());
```

for Except you have to add `using System.Linq` Namespace.

you have to also assigned a Rang for dt1

```
 dt1.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)),
                                            new DataColumn("Acount", typeof(string)),
                                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                                            new DataColumn("Quarter", typeof(string)),
                                            new DataColumn("FY", typeof(int)),
                                            new DataColumn("Income_percent", typeof(int))});
```

Comment: Error at Except()  System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and no extension method 'Except' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: for Except you have to add using System.Linq Namespace.